# Merging Concepts of Distinct, Count and Select in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to find the author(s) (attribute) with the most number of different ISBN(attribute). They are both together in a table named Book.

I understand that distinct and count need to be used, but i'm a little stumped on how to continue:

```
SELECT author
FROM Book
GROUP BY ISBN
HAVING DISTINCT COUNT (ISBN);
```

Unfortunately, this is the incorrect syntax it seems, and I am still unsure how to get the author with the max values out of this.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query below will handle multiple authors having the highest number of ISBN.

```
SELECT  author
FROM    Book
GROUP   BY author
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT ISBN) = (
                                    SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT ISBN)
                                    FROM    Book
                                    GROUP   BY author
                                    ORDER   BY COUNT(DISTINCT ISBN) DESC
                                    LIMIT   1
                                )
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3db216/2).

Answer (score 2):

You want `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT author
FROM Book
GROUP BY author
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT ISBN) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I am guessing that `COUNT(*)` would suffice, but if there are duplicates, then `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is needed.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. However, I believe you meant to say Group by author and not ISBN since we want the author that has the most distinct books.